# Job/jar in Apache Flink doesn't have permisson to file in Docker

Tags: apache-flink, docker-for-windows, csv-parser

I have Apache Flink job for parsing csv-files which works fine in from IntelliJ IDEA on Windows. But when I put my job (jar) in docker-container Apache Flink i have problems with permisson to file with class `FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(...)`. Inside the container i have file: `/opt/flink/data/test2.csv`. The permissions are ok (I can even changed file from my job). For `fileName` I used `/opt/flink/data/test2.csv`, `//opt/flink/data/test2.csv`, `///opt/flink/data/test2.csv`.

**Permissions:**

```
# pwd
/opt/flink/data
# ls -ls
total 16088
 1204 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1231979 Jan 24 15:54 test2.csv
14876 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15231523 Jan 22 19:24 test3.csv
    8 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6623 Jan 24 14:32 test_Home.xlsx
```

**Docker-compose:**

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.16-java8
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/MGubina/Desktop/data:/opt/flink/data

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.16-java8
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
```

**Part of job code:**

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        CsvReaderFormat<Product> csvFormat = CsvReaderFormat.forPojo(Product.class);

        FileSource<Product> csvSource =
//                FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(csvFormat, Path.fromLocalFile(file)).build(); // firsrt version
                FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(csvFormat, new Path(fileName)).build(); // second version

        DataStream<Product> csvInputStream = env.fromSource(csvSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "csv-source");
...
```

**Logs with exception:**

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/flink/data/test2.csv does not exist or the user running Flink ('flink') has insufficient permissions to access it.
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(LocalFileSystem.java:106)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.StreamFormatAdapter.openStream(StreamFormatAdapter.java:157)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.StreamFormatAdapter.createReader(StreamFormatAdapter.java:70)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.checkSplitOrStartNext(FileSourceSplitReader.java:112)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.fetch(FileSourceSplitReader.java:65)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:142)
```

I tried to use different ways of getting Path, but no luck this way.
As long as I have in exception `File file:/opt/flink/data/test2.csv does not exist` I think that problem might be that in local fyle system in Docker (Unix-like)is needed path like `file:///`.

What can I do? Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Do You have both JobManager and TaskManager on the same machine ?

Comment: I don't think that the Flink runs as root, but as another user. You probably need to change the owner with the `chown` command.

Comment: @DominikWosiński, I use docker-compose and inside it i have 2 containers, added docker-compose.yaml in question

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that You are deploying two separate containers `taskmanager` and `jobmanager`, but the file is only available on `jobmanager` and not on `taskmanager`. Can You try to add the correct mounts to the task manager too and try again ?