# File does not exist or the user running Flink ('flink') has insufficient permissions to access it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-flink

I am running Flink in docker compose, with a number of data files mounted into docker volume, and the Flink job read these data files using the File connector.
I tested the file reading logic locally in IntelliJ and it worked. However, when I run these jobs in docker environment, they fail with the following exceptions:

```java
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/quark/data/yelp/user.json.gz does not exist or the user running Flink ('flink') has insufficient permissions to access it.
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(LocalFileSystem.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.StreamFormatAdapter.openStream(StreamFormatAdapter.java:157)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.StreamFormatAdapter.createReader(StreamFormatAdapter.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.checkSplitOrStartNext(FileSourceSplitReader.java:112)
```

To verify that the file exists, I added these preconditions in the `main` function before submitting the Flink jobs:

```java
 Preconditions.checkState(new LocalFileSystem().getFileStatus(inputFilePath) != null,
            "file status must be valid");


        final FileSource<String> source =
            FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineInputFormat(), inputFilePath).build();
        try (StreamExecutionEnvironment env = createExecutionEnvironment()) {

            LOG.info("Running Flink environment with config:" + env.getConfig());

            final DataStream<String> stream =
                env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), targetTopic);

            String pulsarTopic = tenet + "/" + namespace + "/" + targetTopic;
            PulsarSink<String> sink = getPulsar().createSink(pulsarTopic);

            LOG.info("Start writing to sink: " + pulsarTopic);
            stream.sinkTo(sink);
            env.execute();
        }
```

The precondition checks passed, because the files are there and readable. However, the submitted job will still fail.

My hypothesis is that I submitted the job in docker container using `root` user while the flink job is running under `flink`.

However, I used `su flink` to assume `flink` user to test the readability of the mounted data files. I also tried changing the permissions of the data mount folder to allow `rw` operations to everyone. Now I'm not sure what I am missing.

Btw, I'm using the official Flink 1.16.1 docker image as my base image:

```
ARG FLINK_VERSION=1.16.1

FROM flink:${FLINK_VERSION}

# add vim so it's easier to edit files during dev time
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install vim -y
```

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  pulsar:
    image: "apachepulsar/pulsar:3.0.0"
    container_name: pulsar  
    user: root
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
    ports:
      - 6650:6650
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/pulsardata:/pulsar/data
      - ../../bin:/quark/bin
    environment:
      - PULSAR_BIN=/pulsar/bin
     
  jobmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_IMAGE} 
    container_name: flink_master
    ports:
      - "18081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - ../../java/quark-flink-jobs/build/libs:/quark/jobs
      - ../../java/quark-dev-tools/build/libs:/quark/dev-tools
      - ../../bin:/quark/bin
      - ../../data:/quark/data
      - ./flink_job_config:/quark/config
      - ./log:/opt/flink/log
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager   
      - FLINK_BIN=/opt/flink/bin
      - FLINK_JOBS_FOLDER=/quark/jobs
      - YELP_DATA_FOLDER=/quark/data/yelp
      

  taskmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_IMAGE} 
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2  


  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./tmp/localstack/volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I expected the job to run as I'm running it from IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. I found the problem: forgot that I need to mount the data files in both Flink job manager and task managers.

It's exactly the same problem as this one:
[Job/jar in Apache Flink doesn't have permisson to file in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224956/job-jar-in-apache-flink-doesnt-have-permisson-to-file-in-docker)